# How to get images of same height?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to work on a images section, in which they are being rendered from the servers. There are some images which are having different heights. Because of this, I'm unable to align the images in a manner.

NOTE - I have aligned the images, using `display:inline` but currently not able to solve height problem.

Current condition : 
[image]

What I'm trying to follow is similar to Google :
[image]

```css
img.res-img {
  max-width: 350px;
  max-height: 300px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding: 0.6%;
  float: left;
}

.image-result {
  padding-left: 80px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-result" *ngIf="Display('images')">
  <div *ngFor="let item of items$|async">
    <a href="{{item.link}}"><img class="res-img" src="{{item.link}}" onerror="this.style.display='none'"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

It would be great, if someone can help me out with this. Thanks!

UDPATE 1 - What I did from suggestions is this -

```
img.res-image {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
}
```

This is how it looks now, still height problem is not being able to solve!
[image]

UPDATE 2 - After going through answer, this solution seems to be working. But, the resolution of the images has been decreased and aspect ratio is not proper.

```
img.res-img {
  width: 350px;
  height: 300px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding: 0.6%;
  float: left;
}
```

I have removed `max-width` and `max-height` and used `width` and `height`

This is how it looks now : 
[image]

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/recreating-google-images-search-layout-css/

Comment: @ArjanKnol Thanks. Please check my updated question. I followed the link you provided me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove **max-width** & **max-height** property and add just **width** & **height** property in your css

```
    img.res-img {
      width: 350px;
      height: 300px;
      padding-top: 20px;
      padding: 0.6%;
      float: left;
    }

    .image-result {
      padding-left: 80px;
      display: inline;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! It is a great solution! Images has been aligned perfectly as I have expected. But their resolution has been decreased and aspect ratio is not proper.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set one thing alone, i.e. either the height or the width to keep its aspect ratio same.

In your case you need height to be same on all images so you just need to remove the max-width property like this:

```
img.res-img {
  /*max-width: 350px;*/
  max-height: 300px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding: 0.6%;
  float: left;
}
```

You can also refer to thee fiddle I just created: https://jsfiddle.net/387bnaer/

Comment: The OP needs to set one of `width` or `height`. Setting both `max-width` and `min-width` is no problem; the missing `width` or `height` is.

Comment: I think `max-height` would handle it even if I don't pass the height, wouldn't it?

Comment: Not if the pictures are smaller than that!

Comment: Yes that's the other case, but if pictures are smaller, it'll just stretch out if a certain `height` or `width` is provided :)

Comment: @SaurabhSharma I tried your solution, but it is not working.

Comment: @Harshit Check my updated answer or just follow this link: https://jsfiddle.net/387bnaer/

Comment: @SaurabhSharma It's not working for me. Using, `max-height: 100px;` is not the solution. I'm getting all the images in a vertically aligned manner. I have updated my question, tried a different solution. Please check. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Harshit 'max-height: 100px' was never a solution man! Solution was in my answer and the fiddle was an example of that

Comment: @SaurabhSharma I have updated my question again, now I'm facing the problem of resolution and aspect ratio of the images. Thank you for giving time to my question. I really appreciated your help. :)

Comment: @Harshit The problem of the aspect ratio comes from the fact that you are using both `width` and `height` now. You shouldn't.

Comment: @MrLister Thank you for giving time to my question. :) What's the solution then?

Comment: @Harshit It's what I mentioned in my answer! You don't need to use both height and width